# Form Parameter versus Prompts returns different results

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010, prompt

I have an existing process where the Fiscal year and period were being hard-coded into several queries before a macro was being run to manipulate the data into a final report. The format for that information in our accrual DB looks like P02-FY2017. To speed things up, I built a quick form that has two fields on it. One asking for Period as a 2 digit number and another asking for year as a four digit number.

It looked like it's working fine, with results being nearly perfect, except I have a several Purchase Orders missing now that I changed the parameter. I feel that I can almost narrow down that the issue may be my fields on my form.

I tried running the query with the parameter hard coded to "P02-FY2017" and that came back perfect. I tried running the query with a prompt using: **"P"&[Period]&"-FY"&[FYear]** and that came back perfect. The prompt based on the fields built into my form looks like **"P" & [Forms]![Slicer Update]![2DigitPeriod] & "-FY" & [Forms]![Slicer Update]![4DigitFY]**

I'm a novice when it comes to using forms and building their prompts, so I'm inclined to think maybe there is a property on either the query or the form that I need to toggle, but google results haven't been helpful. Any suggestions welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Hit Ctrl+G to open the Immediate window. Type `? [Forms]![Slicer Update]![2DigitPeriod]` and Return. My guess: `2DigitPeriod` is interpreted as number, and you don't get the leading zero. Then use `Format([Forms]![Slicer Update]![2DigitPeriod], "00")`

Comment: What do you mean by prompt? That sounds like you're talking about a message box or a parameter query popup prompt. Can you copy/paste your SQL from the query SQL View? Do you have VBA that executes your query? If so, please copy/paste that too. We can't help otherwise